# What do the initialized Array constructors do?

Tags: c++, eigen

In the `Eigen` documentation I see a lot of these:

```
Array (const Scalar &val0, const Scalar &val1)
Array (const Scalar &val0, const Scalar &val1, const Scalar &val2)
Array (const Scalar &val0, const Scalar &val1, const Scalar &val2, const Scalar &val3)
```

According to the documentation (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Array.html) these constructors "constructs an initialized `N`D vector with given coefficients".

What does that mean? If I do Array(1,2,3), what is the result?

Specifically, what coefficients does it place in each dimension, and how large is the array in each of those respective dimensions? The constructor `Array(1,2,3)`, according to the docs, should construct an 3D array, and initialise its contents with "the given coefficients". How should the result look?

Comment: This is a third party library, not a standard library, so don't expect too much help here. However, based on the documentation, I would assume that it initializes the array with those values. This kind of code probably predates initializer lists which would allow this to be done with a single constructor.

Comment: Ummm... What prevents you from writing this in a code, and printing out the matrix? You can check the output in like 10 lines of code.

Comment: @luk32 compiler errors.

Comment: Well, then you don't have a trouble with what the code really does, now. Maybe try resolving things in order.

Comment: @luk32 you want me to try to fix a compiler error *before* I understand what the code is supposed to be doing?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you are troubling other people for no reason, because you don't have enough skill to check it yourself. It's called putting effort into research before asking a question. You could write 10-15 lines of code, and check the results. If you can't compile it, why do you need to understand it anyways. Sorry.

Comment: @Jason luk32 has a point. Eigen has very good documentation (which you've already seen) and good examples to learn from. You'll understand it better if you try it yourself and from the examples.

Comment: @AviGinsburg the documentation provides no explanation for how these constructors function, as I've stated clearly, with a link. luk32 is suggesting that I figure it out empirically, which is fine, but leads to sloppy coding. I'd much rather understand the code from the ground up.

Comment: @Jason [Here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html) is a tutorial for the Array class on the same website you mentioned.

Comment: @AviGinsburg I've read that at least 3 times.

Comment: Ok I've updated the question, hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructors are for fixed sized Arrays. Assuming the declaration is `Eigen::Array3i` then the constructor you mentioned initializes a 1D int array with three elements initialized to the stated values.

Comment: But the documentation specifically states that it is for 2D,3D, etc. arrays

Comment: @Jason I think there is a misunderstanding vis-a-vis 2D, 3D, 4D. The dimensions are not "physical" dimensions, but rather the length of the single dimension of the array. An `Eigen::Array` can also be of two "physical" dimensions like a matrix, but that is not the case in the mentioned constructors.

Comment: I don't think I follow. When they say 4D vector, they mean 1D vector of length 4?

Comment: My next question was going to be why they're calling them vectors, when vectors are always 1D, but I guess this answers it...

Comment: @Jason Exactly what I mean.

Comment: Wouldn't this constitute a documentation error? I mean, 4D is not the same as 1D of length 4..

Comment: @Jason I'm not the first to say so, but documentation is like sex: when it is good, it is very, very good; and when it is bad, it is better than nothing. That being said, I'm not associated with Eigen, I just use it. I find their documentation to be quite good and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Those constructos allow you to create arrays of sizes up to 4:

```
Eigen::Array<int, 1, 4> a(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Eigen will throw a compile error if you attempt to initialize like this with anything but an `N(1-4) x 1` array. For example:

```
Eigen::Array<int, 1, 3> a(1, 2, 3) //Fine
Eigen::Array<int, 3, 1> a(1, 2, 3) //Fine
Eigen::Array<int, 3, 3> a(1, 2, 3) //Compile error

error: ‘THIS_METHOD_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS_OF_A_SPECIFIC_SIZE
```

I would not be initializing them like this though. There is a tutorial on Eigen initialization [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html) which provides good suggestions for how to initialize arrays for eg:

```
Eigen::Array33 a;
a << 1, 2, 3, 4 ...
```

Which has documentation [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ade5d2e09de50c2ca145037f295542b16).

Or you can use special initializations like:

```
Eigen::ArrayXXf a = Eigen::ArrayXXf::Zero(1, 4) //0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: Yeah but what does `a(1,2,3,4)` actually do? What are the coefficients? A 2x2x2x2 matrix has 16 coefficients, but you've only provided 4...

Comment: Wait, you say array of sizes up to 4. Can you be more specific, you can have 3 sizes for such arrays/matrices. Which is used? Edit, uh ok, I see the docs are quite obscure too. I would also not advise this initialization method unless really needed.

Comment: @Jason sorry, i wasn't clear, i have edited the answer to be more clear.

Comment: Ben, I think this might be a different constructor, because what you're describing is a 1D vector. The docs describe the construction of a 3D vector for `Array(1,2,3)`...